# Firebase deploy error. Server Error. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to deploy a firebase function from my terminal using this comment **firebase deploy**
But getting this error. Cant understand why its happening.

```
deploying functions
functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
functions: packaged functions (27.96 KB) for uploading
functions: Upload Error: Server Error. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Error: Server Error. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
```

Comment: Can you run using `firebase deploy --only functions --debug`  ?

Answer (score 1):

After spending lots of time and investigation I have found that this is a network issue. I am guessing you are trying it from Bangladesh Network.

For some reason Govt has blocked the Google Cloud Storage Upload API, so it is failing to upload.

You should try with VPN. Use Free VPN like Hotspot Shield and try to upload the cloud function. I have finally able to upload my function through VPN. Please try.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error for quite a while and still happened sometimes.
For a rescue, I use a VPN. It is a network issue. Could be happened because of the ISP or may be a country wise block of Google Cloud Storage AP

Answer (score 0):

From firebase debug log  I have found a bit more about this error. I am not sure what could have done for this.

**Request causing trouble or error**

REQUEST PUT https://storage.googleapis.com/gcf-upload-us-central1-1.zip?

[warn] !  functions: Upload Error: Server Error. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established

Comment: From the deployment debug I have got uploading storage service url (https://storage.googleapis.com) is unavailable which is causing this deployment error.

Comment: Are you able to talk directly to cloud storage?  Follow https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects to try.  (Maybe your internet connection is blocking it)

Comment: Hi @Kiana, Yes I can upload files there. I have tried from different internet connection but nothing improved !   Upload Error: Server Error. Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
[2020-05-01T04:55:59.290Z] Error: Client network socket disconnected before secure TLS connection was established
    at TLSSocket.onConnectEnd (_tls_wrap.js:1086:19)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:273:13)
    at TLSSocket.emit (events.js:187:15)
    at TLSSocket.EventEmitter.emit (domain.js:442:20)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1092:12)

Comment: @SohelSarder bhai I am facing the same issue... Did you manage to contact firebase?

Comment: @TasnimAlamShovon later I managed to create it from GCP interface. The above link from Kianna (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects)  will take you into there. However, using firbase CLI still I am getting  error.